# Where should sshfs mounts be placed in the filesystem?

Tags: directory-structure, sshfs, fhs

I have some [`sshfs`](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs) mounts which I want to put in a Linux filesystem location following the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html).

[The standard is strangely silent on where network mounts should be placed](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#REQUIREMENTS):

> ```
> media   Mount point for removeable media
> mnt     Mount point for mounting a filesystem temporarily
> ```

Mounting under `/net` could conflict with NFS autofs mounts from the same hostname.

Where is a sensible place to put `sshfs` mounts given that creating directories directly under `/` is frowned upon?

Comment: The filesystem is irrelevant to where you mount something (if you want to follow FHS). What matters is the content, and what you will use it for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FHS` is defining directory names and usage. Creating a custom directory directly under the root one is considered risky as it might conflict with a future version of the standard or with a new OS owned directory.

Unlike many other Unix and Unix like OSes file system standards (e.g. [freeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=hier&sektion=7) and [Solaris](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E54776/filesystem-5.html#scrolltoc)), the `FHS` fails for some reason to define `/net` as a generic mount point for automounted NFS shares. On the other hand, the `FHS` defines `/mnt` and `/media` for a similar but distinct purposes.

While `/media` is for locally attached devices like CD, DVDs and thumb drives, `/mnt` doesn't restrict the kind of device so should theoretically be usable to store your `sshfs` mount, for example in `/mnt/sshfs/xxx`, but creating an exclusive subdirectory under `/mnt` might conflict with existing admin usage so I wouldn't recommend doing it. `/mnt` is defined to hold file systems temporarily mounted here by the administrator, which doesn't exactly match file systems automatically mounted by a daemon.

There is no way to use `/net` to store `sshfs` mounts as `autofs` configuration is forbidding to have multiple handlers for the same mount point.

As `auto.smb` is suggesting `/cifs` for its root mount point directory, I would simply use `/sshfs`. The risk for `/sshfs` to clash in the future with an OS owned directory is essentially zero.

Excerpt from the `auto.smb` manual page:

```
# Put a line like the following in /etc/auto.master:
# /cifs  /etc/auto.smb --timeout=300
```

Excerpt for the `auto.master` default configuration file:

```
# NOTE: mounts done from a hosts map will be mounted with the
# "nosuid" and "nodev" options unless the "suid" and "dev"
# options are explicitly given.
#
# /net  -hosts
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Patrick](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4358/patrick) wrote in [a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/359162/where-should-sshfs-mounts-be-placed-in-the-filesystem#comment635945_359162), the filesystem is irrelevant to where you mount something (if you want to follow FHS). What matters is the content, and what you will use it for. Actually, the type of the filesystem (whether it is sshfs or NFS or ext4 or anything else) is even more irrelevant.

Where does the **content** below the mountpoint that you are mounting belong in the filesystem tree? Mount it there.

If you are talking about ad-hoc sshfs mounts performed by individual unprivileged users for casual access to files on remote systems (as opposed to, say, something configured in `/etc/fstab`), those users can put them wherever they like, such as an ad-hoc directory under their home directory (which is a likely and obvious place where unprivileged users have permission). The FHS or indeed indeed local sysadmin policies (quite correctly) don't have anything to say about that.

Comment: The file system is irrelevant to the standard but not to the automount program configuration files. The question is about generic mount point locations. What the file system mounted there contain is irrelevant, just like what contain file systems mounted under `/mnt` or `/media`.